# How can I access an attribute inside an img tag inside ui.draggable object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Im trying to get the `src` attribute of an `<img />`, this img is inside an `ui.draggable`.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
            accept: '.draggable',
            activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
            hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');

                console.log( ui.draggable.attr('class') )
            }
        });
```

If i `console.log( ui.draggable.attr('class') )` it returns me the `class` attribute of the `div` dropped. But how can i access the `<img />` attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find()` to select inner elements:

```
console.log( ui.draggable.find("img").attr('src') )
```

Comment: Thanks!! I love you, dude!